# How to convert list of numbers into (temp) table using SQL (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, temp-tables

Here is an example;

I have list of numbers (1,5,8,36) and I want these values as a (temp) table rows. One of the way to do is as follow

```
select 1 as n into ##temp
union
select 5  as n 
union 
select 8 as n
union 
select 36 as n
```

The problem is number list is dynamic . it can have any no of values. So I need a proper systematic way to convert these values into temp table rows.

Comment: If you have more values, add more unions?

Comment: I'm looking for something better than N number of UNION in the SQLs

Comment: UDF to split a string and return a table - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2657/1016183

Comment: What is the source of these numbers? Can your application pass in a TVP instead?

Comment: The numbers are given by SP input? Are they always four numbers?

Comment: @aF. - `The problem is number list is dynamic . it can have any no of values.`

Comment: @Martin '1,5,8,36' is string . What is TVP ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution I use alot...

Supply your list of numbers as a `VARCHAR(MAX)` comma delimeted string, then use one of the many `dbo.fn_split()` functions that people have written on line.

One of *many* examples online...  [SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str)

These functions take a string as a parameter, and return a table.

Then you can do things like...

```
INSERT INTO @temp SELECT * FROM dbo.split(@myList)

SELECT
  *
FROM
  myTable
INNER JOIN
  dbo.split(@myList) AS list
    ON list.id = myTable.id
```

An alternative is to look into Table Valued Parameters.  These allow you to pass a whole table in to a stored procedure as a parameter.  How depends on the framework you're using.  Are you in .NET, Java, Ruby, etc, and how are you communicating with the database?

Once we know more details about your applicaiton code we can show you both the client code, and the SQL stored procedure template, for using Table Valued Parameters.

Comment: SELECT *
        FROM <iterate property="ids" open="(" close=")" conjunction="UNION">
                    SELECT $ids[]$ AS id_val
             </iterate> x
     LEFT JOIN table1 t1
         ON id_val = t1.id_val
     WHERE t1.id_val IS NULL

Comment: I sure this function will work . But I'm hesitant to use ~100 lines function to create temp table. Is there any-other simpler way ?

Comment: @Dexter - There are many split functions all over the internet, and many on Stack Overflow.  Just search through them for one you like, and/or until you understand them and can modify them to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You Can Use Below Query For Select 100 Random Value From 1 To 9

```
Declare @Index Int = 1
Declare @Result Table (Col Int)
While @Index <= 100 Begin
    Insert Into @Result (Col)
    Select FLOOR( RAND() * 10)

    Set @Index = @Index + 1 
End

Select * From @Result
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this for a generic set of numbered rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ORDINAL_POSITION AS NUMBER_VAL 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE ORDINAL_POSITION BETWEEN 1 AND 36
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    create temporary table NS AS (
    SELECT a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h 
    FROM       (SELECT 0 as a UNION SELECT 1) 
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 as b UNION SELECT 2) 
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 as c UNION SELECT 4)
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 as d UNION SELECT 8)
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 as e UNION SELECT 16)
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 as f UNION SELECT 32)
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 as g UNION SELECT 64)
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 as h UNION SELECT 128)
    WHERE a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h BETWEEN 1 AND 200
    ORDER BY 1
)
```

Comment: Hi, please consider adding an explanation as to why this works/should be used instead of just a query.