# match results generated by SQL WHERE IN CLAUSE

Tags: mysql, sql, join

let's see I have a simple `table` like this:

```
name    id
tom     1
jerry   2
...     ...
```

And from the outside, I got a list contains the names (tom, jerry, kettie...)

I am trying to use `WHERE IN` clause to retrieve the id based on the name list.

I can do

```
SELECT id FROM mySimpleTable where name in ('tom','jerry','kettie');
```

So just iterate the `name list` and generate the contents in the parentheses.

This works, but the results is not in the input order, for example, the input is `tom, jerry, kettie`, the expected the result is `1,2,3`, however, the output actually could be in any order.

Then how can I modify the `SQL clause` to make sure I get my input and output matched so that I can do the following process accrordingly. I heard `JOIN` may help in this situation.

Comment: what is a `list contains the names`  you mean a string or another table?

Comment: It is a `java arraylist` contains strings or a `JSON` contains strings, it is not another table.

Comment: You want your result be in the order of the table, or the order in the JSON array?

Comment: whatever, as long as it is 1 to 1 match

Comment: well even when you already got some answer I detect some diferent aproach and some guessing. We will be probably can offer better answer if you provide the expected output and some examples  please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: so you downvote my question?

Comment: No I didnt. I just give you suggestion of how improve your question so other dont downvote you in the future

Comment: but if you could upvote my question, so that I can balance the downvotes(I really did not know why some guys downvote this)....thanks!!!!!!!

Comment: Let make a deal. I will upvote if you improve the question. Because right now I still not sure what order you want and I belive Brian has the right answer. btw  you shouldnt be here just for the rep ;)

Comment: ok man.... I guess you did not get my point. I do not care about the order, I care about the 1 to 1 match. so if the input after `IN` is `(tom, jerry, kettie)`, the output should be `1,2,3`, not `2, 1, 3` or ` 2, 3, 1`

Comment: I ask in my second question... then you want the ID match the order in the element on the JSON array? Then use juegen d answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I heard JOIN may help in this situation.

Yes it can help:

```
SELECT m.id 
FROM mySimpleTable m
JOIN (
  SELECT 'tom' AS name, 1 AS orderNum
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'jerry' AS name, 2 AS orderNum
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'kettie' AS name, 3 AS orderNum
) AS sub
ON m.name = sub.name
ORDER BY sub.orderNum ASC;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2a75/1/0)**</kbd>

This solution can be also used in different RDBMS. `field` is `MySQL` specific.

How it works:

1. Create derived table/subquery with values you need to check and ordering column
2. `JOIN` will return only rows that correspond each other based on name
3. `ORDER BY` column you've added in subquery

Comment: if you could give some brief description... I am not a SQL guy

Comment: @byteBiter Added description

Comment: actually the `order by` is not necessary I guess, right?

Comment: @byteBiter It is crucial, without it result can come in any order

Comment: ha.. I got you, but in this sense, it seems juergen d's answer is more concise. Agree?

Comment: @byteBiter It depends. In SQL Server/Postgresql you can't use his answer. My is more SQL agnostic. You mentioned about `JOIN` so I provided solution. It's up to you which solution you accept. ]

Comment: ok, man... I accept your answer, btw, can you upvote my question? I didn't get the point why some guys downvote this.

Comment: @byteBiter Don't get me wrong but you really should ask such things. As `Juan Carlos Oropeza` spotted your question may be unclear.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id 
FROM mySimpleTable 
where name in ('tom','jerry','kettie')
order by field(name, 'tom','jerry','kettie')
```

Answer (score 1):

just `select id,name from table_a where name in ('tom','jerry','happy')` , you will have the combination of the input name and output id.

Answer (score 0):

this entirely depends on where you're getting the list for your "in" clause.

if it's from somewhere on the outside, you probably should first turn the list into a temp table, adding an id column that indicates the order (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614499/how-to-convert-list-of-numbers-into-temp-table-using-sql-sql-server) answer for a start on how to do that) - and then do an inner join with it.

Answer (score 0):

I did try to run your SQL query, and me for one did get the resultant output in the same order as that of the input. Well, but still it isn't necessary it would happen the same way every time, so the best way to arrange your output in a particular hierarchy is to use the ORDER BY clause. The syntax would be:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table_name
WHERE conditions
ORDER BY column_name;
```

So in your case, the query would read as:

```
SELECT id
FROM mysimpletable
WHERE name
IN('tom','jerry','kettie'....)
ORDER BY id;
```

You can [get more help with MySQL concepts](https://expertassignmenthelp.com/learning-guide/computer-information-technology-guide/mysql-concepts-where-in-having-join-clauses-made-easy-2/) here for further information.

Answer (score -2):

Select 
id 
from mySimpleTable
where name in ('tom','jerry','kettie')
Order by id